# Browse two tables using a cursor

Tags: oracle10g, cursor

In my procedure I have two tables with the same data. I go through my first table through a cursor. Which compares with the second table that I find much the same data. What if, for example in my table_1 I have ten in my data and I have 12 data table2 how to detect missing data in my two table_1 which is traversed by the cursor?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds very much like you'd be better off using the MINUS operator.

```
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT a, b, c
FROM table2
```

This will show you all results that exist in table1 which are not present in table2. In order to show discrepancies both ways, you could do something like this:

```
SELECT z.*, 'In table1, not in table2' problem_description
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table1
  MINUS
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table2   
) z
UNION ALL
SELECT z.*, 'In table2, not in table1' problem_description
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table2
  MINUS
  SELECT a, b, c
  FROM table1   
) z
```

[SQL Fiddle for this answer](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3a650/5/0)